# collective.listingviews:how to use custom fields to display dexterity based image field and richtext field

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'd like to use the collective.listingviews controlpanel to display an image and richtext field. I have the image field working but would like to know if there is a simpler way to retrieve the image. When I try to retrieve the richtext field I end up with a permissions error.

**The details:**

I have a custom dexterity content type (examplecontent) and a collection which retrieves these examplecontent types.

To display the content types I've created a custom 'listingview' for the collection, the goal is that for each retrieved item the following should be displayed:

- A RichText Field named 'body'
- An Image Field named 'screenshot'

This is a mockup of how the layout might behave:
[image: mockup of layout]

To retrieve the image field I'm using the custom tal expression:

```
python:"<img src='%s/view/++widget++form.widgets.screenshot/@@download' />" % item.getObject().absolute_url()
```

To retrieve the body field I'm using the custom tal expression:

```
python:item.getObject().body
```

The image field is working but the richtext field gives the following:

> RichTextValue object. (Did you mean .raw or .output?)

When I change the tal expression for the richtext field to the following:

```
python:item.getObject().body.output
```

I then get the following permissions error:

> Insufficient Privileges
>   You do not have sufficient privileges to view this page. If you believe you are receiving this message in error, contact the site administration.

Comment: Just for diagnostic purposes, what happens if you use "item/getObject/body/output" rather than "python:item.getObject().body.output"?

Comment: I get the following:

__traceback_info__: (<bound method mybrains.getObject of <Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0x6a09940>>, 'body', ['output'])
LocationError: (<bound method mybrains.getObject of <Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0x6a09940>>, 'body')

Comment: Additional, information: I'm really trying to achieve this without having to create an index in the portal_catalog. Trying to see how far I can get with just a TTW approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should change

```
python:"<img src='%s/view/++widget++form.widgets.screenshot/@@download' />" % item.getObject().absolute_url()
```

to:

```
python:"<img src='%s/view/++widget++form.widgets.screenshot/@@download' />" % item.getURL()
```

Since this way means you don't have to get the full object. Note the use of the `getURL()` method.

For the second expression, try something like this:

```
item/getObject/@@text-transform/body
```

or

```
python: item.getObject().restrictedTraverse('@@text-transform/body')
```

*untested*

Comment: using item/getObject/@@text-transform/body
gives the following:
Module plone.app.textfield.browser, line 45, in __call__
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'body'

Comment: I had to use item.getURL() so I'm editing the answer above to reflect that for the image.

Comment: It seems that I needed to add the body field to portal_catalog metadata   {plone_site}/portal_catalog/manage > metadata > Add Metadata and add "body" then {plone_site}/portal_catalog/manage > Advanced > Clear and Rebuild. After doing that I was able to use the following expression: item/body/output. So it can be done, but the portal_catalog step appears to be required and makes it a bit harder for someone working entirely through the web interface.

Comment: Can you try something like, "python: item.getObject().restrictedTraverse('@@text-transform/body')". Please just play with that expression. It should do what you need. Using the portal_catalog is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: The restrictedTraverse approached worked. I removed the metadata from the catalog and it still worked, so this is great. Thanks vangheem!
On another note for the images I'm making use of @@images, for my screenshot I now use the following expression: python:"<img src='%s/@@images/screenshot/preview' />" % item.getURL(). What I like about this is that I can now make use of the image sizing features (preview, thumb, mini, tile,large etc..)